# How to send parameter via hyperlinks from jsp to mvc controller

Tags: spring

Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView editEmp(@RequestParam("id") int id,Model model) {

            System.out.println(id);

            return new ModelAndView("edit");
```

HTML/JSP code :

```
<a href="edit.jsp?id=<%=request.getAttribute("id")%>">Edit </a>
```

Getting below error :

```
Error:The requested resource is not available.
```

Comment: in jsp I have Written  <a href="edit.jsp?id=<%=request.getAttribute("id")%>">Edit </a>

Comment: What mapping for Dispatcher servlet in web.xml? Is it *.jsp?

Comment: No it is .jsp for Dispatcher Servlet

Comment: Then make change in controller mapping from "/edit" to "/edit.jsp"

Answer (score 0):

use the methode value  "/edit" instead of page name  edit.jsp

```
 <a href="/edit?id=<%=request.getAttribute("id")%>">Edit </a>
```

Comment: and test with static value before use request.getAttribute("id")

Comment: Not working,after modifying it becomes http://localhost:2525/edit?id=26,but it should be http://localhost:2525/edit

Comment: if you get  localhost:2525/edit  then you dont't have the parametere in the hyperlink !!!

Comment: if you want localhost:2525/edit  then use : `<a href="/edit">Edit </a> ` but you will lose the parametere

Comment: How to take that parameter to controller ?

Comment: you have 2 solution , you can take it with  `localhost:2525/edit?id=26` or use a spring form and model, you can see this exemple http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Answer (score 0):

Please change mapping for controller from "/edit" to "/edit.jsp"

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

`Error:The requested resource is not available error` comes when server context definition is missing.

Comment: Not working,after modifying it becomes localhost:2525/edit.jsp?id=26,but it should be localhost:2525/edit

Comment: where is server context path?, it should be something  localhost:2525/xxx/edit.jsp?id=26

Comment: Suppose I have Dispalyed employee data in a jsp page by using request.getAttribute() but I want to give one hyperlink to edit that employee data by taking its id,so what I have to do?

Comment: Could you please check your server context defined?

Comment: yeah,server context path comes like http://localhost:2525/EmployeeSearch/edit.jsp?id=26

Answer (score 0):

```
// jstl

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:url var="edit" value="/edit">
  <c:param name="id" value="<%=request.getAttribute("id")%>" />
</c:url>

<a href="<c:out value="${edit}"></c:out>">Edit</a>
```